# How do I add chars from array of chars to a string in Java

Tags: java

I searched the site and found the partially useful StringBuilder method in an answer to another question, but it doesn't seem to want to take the char at index x and y of a 2d char array as a parameter.

Can you suggest a better and more simple method to do this? I say simple because there is a chance something like this will come up in the final, and I would like to be able to remember it. If it's "exotic" to me as a beginning programmer, I probably won't.

I took a fundamentals of programming course in c++, and if memory servers, all I had to do was str+=arrChars[x][y]; That doesn't work for Java, though.

Here is the present state of my toString() method:

```
public String toString()    {

    StringBuilder gardenPrint= new StringBuilder(" | 0 1 2 3\n");
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<garden.length;i++)
        gardenPrint.append(i+ " | ");
        for(j=0;j<garden.length;j++)
            gardenPrint.append(garden[i][j]+" "+(j==garden.length-1) ? "\n":"");
    return gardenPrint;
}
```

Comment: `return Arrays.deepToString(garden);`

Comment: I need to put the indices on the axes, too.

Comment: I wouldn't do that with the `toString()` myself.

Comment: It's part of the assignment. The char array is the board representing a garden where you plant things and a rabbit eats your stuff. The methods are in the assignment spec, and we have to comply with it

Answer (score 1):

Java (nor C++) loops are controlled by indentation. You **need** braces and your ternary needs parenthesis **and** you have to return a `String`. Like,

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder gardenPrint = new StringBuilder(" | 0 1 2 3\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < garden.length; i++) {
        gardenPrint.append(i + " | ");
        for (j = 0; j < garden.length; j++)
            gardenPrint.append(garden[i][j] + " " + ((j == garden.length - 1) ? "\n" : ""));
    }
    return gardenPrint.toString();
}
```

However, we can implement this in a number of ways. For example,

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder gardenPrint = new StringBuilder(" | 0 1 2 3") //
            .append(System.lineSeparator());
    for (int i = 0; i < garden.length; i++) {
        gardenPrint.append(i + " |");
        for (char ch : garden[i]) {
            gardenPrint.append(" ").append(ch);
        }
        gardenPrint.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return gardenPrint.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks much. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use the following two ways to convert a char array to a String:-

```
public class CharArrayToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] chArr = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', 'A', 'B', 'C'};

        String str1 = new String(chArr);
        System.out.println("1st String: " + str1);

        String str2;
        str2 = String.valueOf(chArr);
        System.out.println("2nd String: " + str2);

    }

}
```

**Output**

1st String: 123ABC

2nd String: 123ABC